# Как получить элемент массива по значению одной из переменных?

Tags: php, массивы

Всех приветствую. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить небольшую задачу. Есть массив с ID и название документа, мне нужно получить название документа и цену, зная его ID

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 50
        [pagetitle] => Документ 1
        [price] => 234234
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 48
        [pagetitle] => Документ 2
        [price] => 22341
    )
    и т.д.
)
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$key = array_search($id, array_column($array, 'id'));
echo "Документ: ". $array[$key]['pagetitle']." цена: ". $array[$key]['price'];
```

Документация тут http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php